# Executing functions on dynamically loaded elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my setup:

- Web Page - Does 2 things: Loads in a script called `product-shift.js`. The web page also then uses jQuery to load `content.html` into an element on the webpage. (I do this so I don't have to use the dumb CMS text editor since it sucks)
- `product-shift.js` should take the content of `content.html` and add certain elements to the webpage. As of now, I have this setup to fire when the user clicks on something which works for my current purpose. However, if I want to lets say use a query string in the url to tell `product-shift.js` to show a certain product, I can't think of any way to do this without hardcoding it into my jQuery `.load() callback` that is in my web page.

How can I contain all of the scripting actions within `product-shift.js` and still be able to tell when `content.html` is done loading, even though `product-shift.js` is not the one that is loading `content.html`?

So as of now the layout is as follows:

### Web Page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="product-shift.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#element').load('content.html', function(){
            //LOAD CALLBACK
            //In order for initializeElements() to run on content load it needs
            //to be called from here
        });
    });
</script>
```

### Product-Shift.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    initializeElements() //This runs before Content.html is loaded so it doesn't do anything
});

$(document).on('click', '.elementOfContentHTML', function(){
    if(someElement does not exist) initializeElements();

    run rest of click event
});

var initializeElements = function(){
    //Add some elements to the web page based on Content.html
}
```

So is there a way for me to automatically call `initializeElements()` from `product-shift.js` without needing to manually tell the program when to run it?

Comment: You said "`product-shift.js` uses jQuery to load `content.html`" but then later said "... even though `product-shift.js` is not the one that is loading `content.html`" — which is it?

Comment: @VoteyDisciple sorry, need a comma in there and some clarification, the web page is doing the loading

Comment: Could you post your code? it might be easier to understand that way

Comment: Define a function in `product-shift.js` that does all the work, and call that function from the `.load()` callback.

Comment: @Barmar right, and that's kind of what I have now, but is there anyway to do that without having to call the function from `.load()`? The only other way I could think of would be to use `setInterval()` and check if the elements exist... but not sure how that would effect performance

Comment: That's the only other way I can think of, but it seems like a poor design.

Comment: @Barmar the `setInterval()` or the whole thing is poor design?

Comment: @Adjit The `setInterval()` plan. Callbacks are generally preferable.

Comment: What's wrong with your callback plan?

Comment: @JonathanBrooks nothing is wrong with it, I was wondering if there was a different way to do it where I didn't need to use a callback. Not sure why people are voting to close, this question definitely doesn't need any code

Comment: If you know which elements you are looking for, then you can use a MutationObserver to see when that element is loaded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know what elements you are looking for, then you can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) like

```js
//In the product list page
var target = document.querySelector('#element');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    //check whether our target element is loaded
    if ($(mutation.addedNodes).is('#child')) {
      //call the initializer
      $('#log').append('<div>Initialize</div>')

      //no need to observe further
      observer.disconnect();
    }
  });
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = {
  childList: true
};

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);



//in the main page
jQuery(function() {
  //to simulate the ajax request
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#log').append('<div>add</div>')
    $('#element').append('<div id="child">a</div>');
  }, 1000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element"></div>

<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Never knew this existed, but its exactly what I was looking for.